# How to write HexStringToData in java the same as Swift Example?

Tags: java, android, swift2, hex

I writing and app in Java using Android studio and I would appreciate a little help, as I have this example below in Swift 2.3 :

```
private func hexStringToData(hexString: String) -> NSData {

    print("String: \(hexString)")

    let chars = Array(hexString.characters)

    let numbers = 0.stride(to: chars.count, by: 2).map {
        UInt8(String(chars[$0 ..< $0+2]), radix: 16) ?? 0
    }
    return NSData(bytes: numbers, length: numbers.count)

}
```

I would like to know if it is possible to have the equivalent in Java, I've tried the code below, but this seems to fail on : Invalid array range:6 to 6 an example of the code is below:

```
private static byte[]hexStringToData (String hexString) {

    Log.e("[hexStringToData]String", ":" + hexString);

    int len = hexString.length();
    byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
        data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(hexString.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                + Character.digit(hexString.charAt(i+1), 16));
    }
    return data; 
}
```

Can someone please tell me where it is I'm going wrong, thanks in advance....

This is the string : A4728E4491AA598E0473C2EB860C8872B8F53630329C97B8D7FF1A0F9BC5‌​487E971CAD562E7C4C7A‌​2847CFB4681F0E563B66‌​7A6E6E09FBF60378A302‌​44E0981A46CB17BA3F22‌​8A4DD89360B3C4CB156D‌​794E9ADE22F55F55A6A7‌​E76A726588B1C615774E‌​713F6D1E59D7B1D82E2B‌​913330AB92C1DB595054‌​0FFC2C9B6ED0889000A9‌​51778F3A82C1CCB16651‌​DFFAA6C6A40EEE9FFB24‌​217F85C57A190757BF57‌​4ADC9D9A7E38DBC3B7B3‌​61AFC0D3C36A76916DEF‌​493633708E9D9BFB639F‌​8D2499C2A71D6E8A52F6‌​34050BD3FF1260502E8A‌​2834B1FB56BED29CAB1B‌​3993EA669313ECD63FC9‌​911F1BFF1EA4AAC5410D‌​E9E2D80AE5B05F701EDD‌​4F06B5CD532

Comment: Show the invocation that you're having a problem with. Your code seems essentially identical to some I have that (seems to!) work fine (assuming the string is an even number of hex digits).

Comment: when I its passed through the converting  this line :  data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(hexString.charAt(i), 16) << 4) shows me an error in the console of java.lang,IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invaild array range 6 to 6, Its a rsa file I'm trying to convert, Does this help?

Comment: You need to show the _specific_ `String` you're passing in to `hexStringToData() ` that's causing the problem.  The function will only work for strings with an _even_ number of hex digits -- an odd number of characters would definitely blow it up, as possibly would non-hex characters.

Comment: Thanks Eric Aya, edited. I take it that you marked the question down for that?

Comment: That was me, for not including the example originally (now reversed). The problem appears to be "odd" characters (line-endings?) in the middle of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I made a school boy error : hexStringToData(file), "file-0001.rsa", I was trying to convert the file name itself and not the actual file inself, so my length was 13 because of the file name and the length should of been 512 of the file.